# Packages download defaults to be sandboxed

Tags: su, download, sandbox

Why most Linux packages download defaults to be operated under sandbox canceling su  privilege ?
E.g. is on debian

`W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file` ...

Please one elaborate sandbox close related matter on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading files doesn’t require any special privileges, so when it can, `apt` drop privileges to do so. There are a number of conditions which need to be met: the configured “reduced privilege” user (`_apt` by default) must exist, must be allowed to write to the download target, and in some cases, must be allowed to read from the “download” source (when that involves copying files rather than downloading from a remote host). If those conditions aren’t met, `apt` falls back to downloading as root, rather than aborting the operation entirely.

`apt` can use external download helpers (in `/usr/lib/apt/methods` by default), which makes privilege-dropping all the more interesting.

The latest versions of `apt` can also use seccomp filtering, but that’s disabled by default because [it fails on some Debian architectures](https://bugs.debian.org/890489).